# The problem with the calculation of the price of all goods on the site. Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

To calculate the price of a product, I created a function that iterates through all the products using the .ItemtotalPrice class and gets the value from the value attribute, then adds the value passed to the function before adding them. When changing the quantity of one product, everything works fine, but when changing the quantity of another product, the price for all goods changes with errors

**working function for the calculation of one product, but with different**

```
function conversionPrice(id) {                                   
    let newCnt = $(#count__input${id}).val();                                   
    let itemPrice = $(#itemPrice_${id}`).attr('value');
    let itemRealPrice = newCnt * itemPrice;$('#itemTotalPrice_' + id).text(itemRealPrice + '$');
    totalConversionPrice(itemRealPrice);
}
```

**non-working function with the calculation of the total price of all items in the cart**

```
function totalConversionPrice (res) {
    let newCnt = $('#all_price').val();
    $('.itemTotalPrice').each(function() {         
        let price = $(this).attr('value');         
        total = newCnt + price;     
    });     
    ob = Number(total) + res;      
    $('#all_price').text(ob + '$'); 
}
```

**the website looks like this**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kUUT.png)

```
foreach ($row as $key => $cartProducts) : ?>
    <section class="product" id="product<?php echo $cartProducts['id_product'] ?>">

        <div class="product__img">
            <img src="/assets/img/<?= $cartProducts['img'] ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="product__title">
            <?= $cartProducts['name'] ?>
        </div>

        <div class="product__count">
            <div class="count">

                <div class="count__box">
                    <input type="number" id="count__input<?= $cartProducts['id_product'] ?>" class="count__input" min="1" name="count_products<?= $cartProducts['id_product'] ?>" max="50" step="1" value="1" onchange="conversionPrice(<?= $cartProducts['id_product'] ?>)">
                </div>
                <div class="count__controls">
                    <button type="button" id="increment" class="count__up" onclick="stepper(this, <?= $cartProducts['id_product'] ?>)">
                        <img src="/assets/img/count_up.svg" alt="increase">
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" id="decrement" class="count__down" onclick="stepper(this, <?= $cartProducts['id_product'] ?>)" ;>
                        <img src="/assets/img/count_down.svg" alt="decrease">
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="product__price<?= $cartProducts['id_product'] ?>">
            <span class="itemPrice" id="itemPrice_<?= $cartProducts['id_product'] ?>" value="<?= $cartProducts['price'] ?>">
                <?= $cartProducts['price'] ?>$
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="product__total-price<?= $cartProducts['id_product'] ?>">
            <span class="itemTotalPrice" id="itemTotalPrice_<?= $cartProducts['id_product'] ?>" value="<?= $cartProducts['price'] ?>">
                <?= $cartProducts['price'] ?>$
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="product__controls">
            <button type="button">
                <img src="/assets/img/x.svg" class="btn_delete" id="delete_id<?= $cartProducts['id_product']; ?>" onclick='deleteProduct(this, <?= $cartProducts['id_product']; ?>)'>
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<div class="cart-footer__price" id="all_price"><?= ROUND($sum[0]['SUM(price)'], 2) ?>$</div>
```

`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, is this problem really a PHP problem?

Comment: As your question is (or appears to be) regarding javascript/jquery, please provide enough relevant HTML as **rendered HTML** - ie as a sample as seen by the js/jquery/browser.

Comment: Why does your calculation involve that `newCnt`? That is the last total price you calculated, before you made any changes to the product quantities, is it not? So why are you adding this, how is that supposed to make sense?

Comment: `total = newCnt + price;` - you are not even _adding_ to total inside your loop there, you are _overwriting_ this variable in each loop iteration.

Comment: The whole approach doesn't seem quite correct - eg reading the old total, only adding parts, converting to a number *after* it's already NaN - but your specific issue will likely be:  on first pass you do `$('#all_price').text(ob + '$'); ` - so "allprice" now = "0.00$" then `newCnt = $('#all_price').val()` - so newCnt will be "0.00$" which, if you concat with a number will give you "0.00$0.00" - which is NaN.   Convert your `.val()`s to numbers at the time you read them.